# How can I get min, max datetime of NULL occurence

Tags: sql-server, datetime, null

I have the following data and I am trying to think of a way of getting the `min(datetime)`, `max(datetime)` of each occrence of the null values throughout the year.  I tried getting duplicate values but I was unable to group dupes.  Can someone point me in the right direction.

```
 Datetime           Tagname Value
 09/18/2015 9:52:50 Tag_1   26670
 09/18/2015 9:53:00 Tag_1   26670
 09/18/2015 9:53:10 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:53:20 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:53:30 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:55:00 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:55:10 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:55:20 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:55:30 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:55:40 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:55:50 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:56:00 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:56:10 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:56:20 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:56:30 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:56:40 Tag_1   NULL
 09/18/2015 9:56:50 Tag_1   26821
 09/18/2015 9:57:00 Tag_1   26821
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: In the example the desired outcome should be.                                                                                                  Tagname Start                   End
Tag_1 09/18/2015 9:53:10 09/18/2015 9:56:40

Comment: You want the min datetime where value is null, and the max datetime where value is null? (if so, `select min(datetime), max(datetime) from t where value is null`).

Comment: @Amit is spot-on with his comment.  Just add a `WHERE` clause for `null` values and then get the min and max.  But do you have only one day or could there be multiple?

Comment: This is the qry I use the read the data.  select datetime, tagname, value from AnalogHistory
        where TagName in ('tag_1')
        and DateTime > '01/01/15 00:00:00'   and DateTime <= getdate().     There will be values other than NULL value interspersed throughout the data ranges............................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear, but I'm guessing that you want to figure out the start & end dates of continuous ranges of NULL values, and you can do it like this:

```
select
  min(datetime), max(datetime)
from
(
  select Datetime, Value, RN - row_number() over (order by Datetime) as GRP
  from
  (
    select 
      *, row_number() over (order by datetime asc) as RN 
    from table1
  ) X
  where
    Value is NULL
) Y
group by GRP
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d6c1b/1). I added few values to your data to get more ranges.

The innermost row_number will number all rows, the outer one only the rows that have NULL (because other rows are being filtered away). This way when the difference between the values is equal, the rows belong to the same range.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN([Datetime]) MinDate
      ,MAX([Datetime]) MaxDate
FROM TableName
WHERE Value IS NULL
```

Comment: In my initial entry i supplied one instance of data.  but there will be multiple instances of this type of data through out a date range.